# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '5')

Tags: solidity, ethereum-wallet-dapp, hardhat, hardhat-deploy, goerli

```
Error: ERROR processing /home/surajsahoo/hh-fcc/hardhat-fund-me-fcc/deploy/01-deploy-fund-me.js:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '5')
    at Object.module.exports [as func] (/home/surajsahoo/hh-fcc/hardhat-fund-me-fcc/deploy/01-deploy-fund-me.js:27:47)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at DeploymentsManager.executeDeployScripts (/home/surajsahoo/hh-fcc/hardhat-fund-me-fcc/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/DeploymentsManager.ts:1219:22)
    at DeploymentsManager.runDeploy (/home/surajsahoo/hh-fcc/hardhat-fund-me-fcc/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/DeploymentsManager.ts:1052:5)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (/home/surajsahoo/hh-fcc/hardhat-fund-me-fcc/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/index.ts:438:5)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (/home/surajsahoo/hh-fcc/hardhat-fund-me-fcc/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:308:14)
    at Environment.run (/home/surajsahoo/hh-fcc/hardhat-fund-me-fcc/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:156:14)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (/home/surajsahoo/hh-fcc/hardhat-fund-me-fcc/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/index.ts:584:32)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (/home/surajsahoo/hh-fcc/hardhat-fund-me-fcc/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:308:14)
    at Environment.run (/home/surajsahoo/hh-fcc/hardhat-fund-me-fcc/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:156:14)
    at DeploymentsManager.executeDeployScripts (/home/surajsahoo/hh-fcc/hardhat-fund-me-fcc/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/DeploymentsManager.ts:1222:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at DeploymentsManager.runDeploy (/home/surajsahoo/hh-fcc/hardhat-fund-me-fcc/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/DeploymentsManager.ts:1052:5)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (/home/surajsahoo/hh-fcc/hardhat-fund-me-fcc/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/index.ts:438:5)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (/home/surajsahoo/hh-fcc/hardhat-fund-me-fcc/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:308:14)
    at Environment.run (/home/surajsahoo/hh-fcc/hardhat-fund-me-fcc/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:156:14)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (/home/surajsahoo/hh-fcc/hardhat-fund-me-fcc/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/index.ts:584:32)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (/home/surajsahoo/hh-fcc/hardhat-fund-me-fcc/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:308:14)
    at Environment.run (/home/surajsahoo/hh-fcc/hardhat-fund-me-fcc/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:156:14)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (/home/surajsahoo/hh-fcc/hardhat-fund-me-fcc/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/index.ts:669:5)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Above mentioned error is coming while deploying. Below provided is the js file **01-deploy-fund-me.js**

```sol
const { networkConfig } = require("../helper-hardhat-config")
const { network } = require("hardhat")
const { verify } = require("../utils/verify")

module.exports = async ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) => {
    const { deploy, log } = deployments
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
    const chainId = network.config.chainId

    //const ethUsdPriceFeedAddress = networkConfig[chainId]["ethusdpricefeed"]
    let ethUsdPriceFeedAddress
    if (chainId == "31337") {
        const ethUsdAggregator = await deployments.get("MockV3Aggregator")
        ethUsdPriceFeedAddress = ethUsdAggregator.address
    } else {
        ethUsdPriceFeedAddress = networkConfig[chainId]["ethusdpricefeed"]
    }

    const fundMe = await deploy("FundMe", {
        from: deployer,
        args: [ethUsdPriceFeedAddress], //put price feed address
        log: true,
        waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmations || 1,
    })

    //     if (!developmentChains.includes(network.name)) {
    //         await verify(fundMe.address, [ethUsdPriceFeedAddress])
    //     }
}

module.exports.tags = ["all", "fundme"]
```

Below mentioned is the **helper-hardhat-config** file

```sol
const networkConfig = {
    31337: {
        name: "localhost",
    },
    5: {
        name: "goerli",
        ethusdpricefeed: "0xD4a33860578De61DBAbDc8BFdb98FD742fA7028e",
    },
}
const developmentChain = ["hardhat", "localhost"]

module.export = {
    networkConfig,
    developmentChain,
}
```

Comment: can you post your networkConfig var from the `helper-hardhat-config` file?

Comment: I have added the helper-hardhat-config file in the question

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are running code from here https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/hardhat-fund-me-fcc

I had checked out it and run, it works well.

From the error message, error happened at deploy/01-deploy-fund-me.js line 27,  even line number is missing in your post, but I can guess that issue code is at`ethUsdPriceFeedAddress = networkConfig[chainId]["ethusdpricefeed"]`, and chain id is 5, according to `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '5')`, that means `networkConfig` is undefined.

I noticed that some variables are in lower case (like 'ethusdpricefeed') in your post, but in the original repository they are camel-style(like 'ethUsdPriceFeed'). Compare your code with original repository to find out differences.

Comment: Thank you so much. The problem was with the helper-hardhat-config file. It should be "module.exports" and not "module.export"